# Opening and closing screen effects? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How to open screen with effect, moving from the bottom to top and when closing top to bottom.

Just like Facebook notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're referring to a modal dialog. You can push a new view controller modally onto an existing one like so:

```
[viewController presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

This will give you the bottom-to-top animation of modal appearing.

Then later on you can dismiss with:

```
[viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

...which gives you to top-to-bottom dismissal effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[yourViewController presentModalViewController: vc animated: YES];
[vc.parent dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```